# importing file using class on lines

Tags: python, class, object, import, constructor

I am importing a class module, and then opening a text file. Maybe I am not understanding classes right, but I was thinking that if I called the **init** constructor it would take the information from the file and put it in that format. I have read a lot of questions asking how to do this on this site, about people having trouble reading a text file and using their constructor on it- but haven't seen any answers that combine the import file and class component. here is my code for the class:

```
class Apartments:
      def __init__(self,apartNum, rent, rooms, bath):
            self.apartNum=apartNum
            self.rent=rent
            self.rooms=rooms
            self.bath=bath
```

Here is the file I'm importing it to :

```
import sys
sys.path.append("/Users/kabe/Desktop/Apartments")

import Apartments

dataFile = open('apartmentData.txt').readlines()
```

## everything after this point is code I tried out but doesn't work.

```
apartmentsList = []
for line in dataFile:
    strippedLine=line.split()
    apartmentsList.append(Apartments)

for apartment in apartmentsList:
    print(apartment.apartNum + ' ' + apartment.rent + ' ' + apartment.rooms + ' ' + apartment.bath)
openfile()
```

this code gives me the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/lortiz/Desktop/Memes/College/homework/l_kennedy_lab8_wk9.py", line 13, in <module>
    print(apartment.apartNum + ' ' + apartment.rent + ' ' + apartment.rooms + ' ' + apartment.bath)
AttributeError: module 'Apartments' has no attribute 'apartNum'
```

I'm trying to achieve class objects that look like this from the text file I am importing:

```
apt_1= Apartments(111,1000,1,1)
apt_2= Apartments(112,2000,2,1)
apt_3= Apartments(113,2500,2,2)
apt_4= Apartments(114,3000,3,2)
apt_5= Apartments(115,3500,3,3)
```

Thanks!

Comment: Python *is* case-sensitive, and also scope-sensitive. “Apartments” is a module. The way you imported, “Apartments” is a reference to a module, you have to use Apartments.Apartments” to refer to the class, and you have to create a new instance to be able to refer to .apartNum on an instance.

Comment: BTW calling the class “Appartments” is not very good. An instance of this class is about *an* appartment, so it would be a lot less confusing to call the class Apartment.

Answer (score 0):

```
apartmentsList.append(Apartments(*strippedLine))
```

You should add Appartments instance, not the class itself.